# How to save and load the added player name

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have searched and searched for how to save and load the added player name to a `tableview` after apps starts, or leaving the view, but I found out nothing.

Hope someone can help me with this issue.

Below is my code :

```
@interface PlayersViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayersViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.players count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView
                                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.players   removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}


- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewControllerDidSave:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AddPlayer"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController =
        segue.destinationViewController;
        PlayerDetailsViewController
        *playerDetailsViewController =
        [[navigationController viewControllers]
         objectAtIndex:0];
        playerDetailsViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

- (void)playerDetailsViewController:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
                       didAddPlayer:(Player *)player
{
    [self.players addObject:player];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.players count] - 1
                       inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

```html
@interface PlayerDetailsViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayerDetailsViewController
{
     NSString *game;
}

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{
 [self.delegate playerDetailsViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
 Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
 player.name = self.nameTextField.text;
 [self.delegate playerDetailsViewController:self
                                  didAddPlayer:player];
    
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (indexPath.section == 0)
  [self.nameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
 NSLog(@"dealloc PlayerDetailsViewController");
}
```

Comment: Your question is quite wide. Can you ask concrete question?

Comment: Yes I can :)

When I add a player to my tableView, and the i close the app and start it again, the player names, that I has added is removed, so my table is empty. So the question is, how to keep the names remembered in the tableView

Comment: Yes the done button is from playerDetailVC, and I am dismissing the Detailed ViewController

Comment: You mean to show the players after closing and re-opening the App?
then you need to keep your player name in some DB. May be Coredata or sqlite. then when re-opening the app, you fetch your players and show it in the table.

Comment: Yes something like that :) I have added the PlayerDetailVC code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to save your data between application launches, you can rely on this topics:

- [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html)

  [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults)

  [Realm](https://realm.io)

  other stuff, like your own server, custom sqlite, etc...

I recommend you start with CoreData guide, that allows you to easy save data between launches.
Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out